# How do I compare one column in my dataframe to my rowcount?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
prefix_df=['ADR2','ADR6','ADRC','ADRU','BUT000','BUT020','BUT021_FS','BUT050','BUT0ID','BUT100']

def get_rowcount_csv():
    for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='decrypted/'):
        if my_bucket_object.key.endswith('.csv'):
            filename = my_bucket_object.key.split('/')[-1]
            if filename.split('.')[0] in prefix_df:
                df = pd.read_csv(f's3://path/to/file/{filename}', sep='|')
                numlines=len(df)
                print(f'{filename} ' + ":" f' {numlines}')
                df_midas = pd.read_csv(f's3://path/to/file/LOAD_STAT.csv', sep= '|', usecols=['TGT_INSRT_CT', 'TGT_TBL_NM'])
                df_filtered = df_midas[df_midas['TGT_TBL_NM'].isin(prefix_df)]
                df_filtered = df_filtered.sort_values('TGT_TBL_NM')
                df_filtered = df_filtered[['TGT_INSRT_CT']]
                if df_filtered == numlines:
                    print("Match")

get_rowcount_csv()
```

I have my code above. It reads the csv files in my s3 bucket that matches the names of the CSV in my list `prefix_df`. Then it does a row count of those records. After that, it reads another CSV file in my s3 bucket that has the number of records per table. I am trying to validate that the row count I am doing of each CSV matches values in the the column `TGT_INSRT_CT` in my `LOAD_STAT.csv` file. When I run my code above, it returns this error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` I need some help fixing my code to get it to work.

Comment: `df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered['TGT_INSRT_CT'] == numlines]`

Comment: thanks for your response. i ran this and is it checking to see if `numlines` matches `'TGT_INSRT_CT'`? i see it is doing a comparison and printing out the values but how do i actually check if they match and print "True" or "Match" or something..

Comment: You could just use `df_filtered['TGT_INSRT_CT'] == numlines`. This will return a series of True/False

Comment: ok that makes sense. this is what i have now `df_filtered = df_filtered['TGT_INSRT_CT'] == numlines` but now it's returning True/False by comparing each value in `numlines` to all the values in `TGT_INSRT_CT` then going to the next value in `numlines` and comparing that value to all the values in `TGT_INSRT_CT`. i think i have to fix my forloop

Comment: `numlines` is just a single value, there is no "next value in `numlines`". Each time through the loop you're processing a different df, and `numlines` is the number of rows in that df.

Comment: oh i see. i have to find a way to iterate through numlines to go to the next record in the dataframe and compare it to the next table in my prefix_df then

Comment: `df_midas` seems to be the same df every time. Why are you reading it in the loop?

Comment: It seems like your logic is backwards. Instead of looping through all the files in the bucket and checking if it's in `prefix_df`, loop through `prefix_df` and read that file from S3.

Comment: ugh this is so confusing. i think the issue is that i am comparing  `TGT_INSRT_CT` to every record in that matches `numlines` when i just want to compare `numlines` to the first row, the second table count from numlines to the second row and so on. i think i need a different approach to counting the records in the csv

Comment: I think you should create a second dataframe with the prefix and corresponding numlines. Then you can join the two df's and compare the corresponding rows.

Comment: i dont think that would work because numlines will be different every day when this is automated. i think ill make 2 separate functions, one for rowcount and another for comparing the LOAD_STAT.csv

Comment: Why is it a problem if it changes every day? You're going to create a new df each day.

Comment: nevermind i figured it out. this is what i did: `df_filtered = df_filtered[(df_filtered['TGT_INSRT_CT'] == numlines) & (df_filtered['TGT_TBL_NM'] == filename.split('.')[0])]`

Comment: can you help me figure out how to replace the empty dataframe with the number "0"? in my excel sheet, wherever the `TGT_INSRT_CT` is 0, reads as an empty dataframe in my code. i want the actual number "0" to show up when I print the dataframe at the end. i tried this `df_filtered['TGT_INSRT_CT'].replace('',0, inplace=True)` but it printed nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really  pandas expert. This sounds like a new question, you should post it as that.